# How to properly use the try catch in perl that error.pm provides?

Tags: perl, error-handling, try-catch

I have found that there is the module [Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Error) that provides try and catch functionality like in java.  But I am confused at how you can print the exception that returns.

I would like to understand how to do the following

```
try {
    // do something that will fail!

} catch (Error e) {
    // Print out the exception that occurred
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

How do I get the print of the error with the stack trace?

Comment: Updated answer, now that perl has native support https://stackoverflow.com/a/72450876/124486

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're probably better off using [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try%3a%3aTiny) which will help you avoid a number of [pitfalls with older `perl`s](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5140delta#Exception_Handling).

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
        die "foo";
} catch {
        warn "caught error: $_";
};
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. You dump things in log files by logging them and you create exceptions by using `die` or `croak`. Are you asking how to put together exception objects etc? That would be a separate question.

Comment: When using `Try::Tiny`, also be aware that the blocks are new calling contexts; if you `return` from inside a `try`/`catch`/`finally` block, it just returns from the block, not the outer subroutine.

Comment: You can use instead [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) which is a perfect implementation of try-catch block using perl filter.

Answer (score 56):

Last I checked, [Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Error) was deprecated.   But here's how you would do it without that module:

```
eval {
    die "Oops!";
    1;
} or do {
    my $e = $@;
    print("Something went wrong: $e\n");
};
```

Basically, use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) instead of `try`, [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) instead of `throw`, and look for the exception in [`$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24@). The true value at the end of the eval block is part of an idiom to prevent `$@` from unintentionally changing before it is used again in Perl versions older than 5.14, see [P::C::P::ErrorHandling::RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval](http://p3rl.org/Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aErrorHandling%3a%3aRequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval) for details. For example, this code suffers from this flaw.

```
# BAD, DO NOT USE WITH PERLS OLDER THAN 5.14
eval {
    die "Oops!";
};
if (my $e = $@) {
    print("Something went wrong: $e\n");
}
# BAD, DO NOT USE WITH PERLS OLDER THAN 5.14
```

---

But note that many Perl operations do not raise exceptions when they fail; they simply return an error code. This behavior can be altered via [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) for builtins and standard modules.  If you're using `autodie`, then the standard way of doing try/catch is this (straight out of the autodie perldoc):

```
use feature qw(switch);

eval {
   use autodie;

   open(my $fh, '<', $some_file);

   my @records = <$fh>;

   # Do things with @records...

   close($fh);

};

given ($@) {
   when (undef)   { say "No error";                    }
   when ('open')  { say "Error from open";             }
   when (':io')   { say "Non-open, IO error.";         }
   when (':all')  { say "All other autodie errors."    }
   default        { say "Not an autodie error at all." }
}
```

For getting a stacktrace, look at [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html).

Comment: See [the BACKGROUND section in `Try::Tiny` docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND) for problems you can run into with older `perl`s when using `eval` for exception handling.

Comment: [Exception handling was fixed in 5.14.0](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5140delta#Exception_Handling)

Comment: I am new to perl, how do I find out what is deprecated?  I don't want to use eval { because it doesn't feel natural.  I come from a java/C++/C# background. So, if I shift to Try::Tiny that is newer and more stable?

Comment: Things like Try::Tiny are just sugar wrapping; it's still `eval` under the covers.

Answer (score 8):

If you want something a bit more powerful than Try::Tiny, you might want to try looking at the [TryCatch](http://search.cpan.org/~ash/TryCatch-1.003002/lib/TryCatch.pm) module in CPAN.

Answer (score 4):

## Native `try`/`catch`/`finally`.

[Perl now has native support for `try`/`catch`/`finally`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68007873/124486). You can use it like this. As of [Perl v5.36, It's currently experimental.](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18760)

```perl
use experimental "try";
try { die 42 }
catch ($err) {
  print "got $err"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) has been broken with the new version 0.006020 of [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare) and there seems to be no intention of fixing it. The perl core developers team also complained about the funky stuff TryCatch was relying on to make it work.

Instead there is a new implementation called [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try), which is a perfect replacement.

There is no need to have semi colon on the last brace like Try::Tiny.

You can also do exception variable assignment like

```
  try
  {
    # something
  }
  catch( $e )
  {
    # catch this in $e
  }
```

It also works using class exception like

```
  try
  {
    # something
  }
  catch( Exception $e )
  {
    # catch this in $e
  }
```

And it also supports `finally`. Its features set make it quite unique.

Full disclosure: I have developed this module when TryCatch got broken.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO [`Syntax::Keyword::Try`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try) is a better option than `Try::Tiny` for most cases.

`Try::Tiny` is an order of magnitude slower than either eval or `Syntax::Keyword::Try`. It depends on your application if this is a problem or not. For many applications its not important.

Also if you are a visitor from another language, `Try::Tiny` has syntax quirks which make it not quite the try/catch you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, the old Error module is deprecated, but it has continued to work for me long after. It's been a while since I last checked if its still working.  I tried some of the "better" replacements and found them all lacking, so I still use Error.

Here's a sample from some code that's pretty straight forward and prints the error that was caught.  This is from an app I wrote that uses Storable to store and retrieve serialized perl objects to an MLDBM backend file.

```
use Error(':try');
...

     try {
        $obj = retrieve( $objfile );
      } catch Error::Simple with {
        my $E = shift;
        warn "Caught error $E";
      };
```

This returns a message something like:

```
Caught error Not a HASH reference at ./json2text.pl line 12.
```

If you want the full stack trace, you can either run the code under the debugger, or you can read about the stacktrace method on the perldoc for the Error class itself.  I never found it necessary to have apps not running under the debugger to print full stack traces, so I don't have any examples of that in my collection to paste a sample from.

I hope this helps. Sometimes you just have to wait for a dinosaur to show up.